# replace function seems failed using Flyway 4.2.0 to migrate postgres db

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, flyway

I'm using flyway in container created using postgres:9.1 image. Here what I did:

1. copied flyway-4.2.0, sql files and config file needed into the container.
2. loaded baseline sql with psql --file.
3. run flyway-4.2.0/flyway -configFile=filesystem: baseline && flyway -configFile=filesystem:. The parameters in config file are:
   db_username, db_password, path_of_sql_file, list_of_schema

From the log, the migration is done successfully. The old schema is droped, new schema created.Tables all seems fine too.

But when I check the function, It is the old version in the baseline that still querying on old schema. I have replaced the function in a sql file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function XXX_XXX (para1, para2)
....
SELECT xxx FROM new_schema.xxxx INTO xx
....
```

From the logs, that version is successfully migrated, yet the function is still:

```
XXX_XXX (para1, para2)
....
SELECT xxx FROM old_schema.xxxx INTO xx
....
```

Seems all the "CREATE OR REPLACE function" is failed and logs shows nothing.
I know this issue should have been fixed in flyway 4.0. So really don't have a clue about it.

Comment: Running with debug on (`-X`) when migrating will help show you the SQL that is actually being run and will help narrow your troubleshooting.

Comment: When I use flyway 3.2.1, The new function will be created on new schema while just use function_name but not new_schema.function_name in statement. Flyway 4.2.0 seems must specify the schema when using 'CREATE OR REPLACE'. So it's my script that need to be fixed